# Create a numbered checklist

Tags: formatting, enumerate

I want to make a numbered checklist document. For example,

1.1 *whitespace* [ ] *More whitespace* Text

1.2 *whitespace* [ ] *More whitespace* Text

...

2.1 *whitespace* [ ] *More whitespace* Text

I would also like to be able to nest it to create something as follows.

*whitespace* 2.1.1 *whitespace* [ ] *More whitespace* Text

I want all the text to be the same size.

Comment: Basically this is pretty easy with `enumitem` ... What is the `[]` meant to be there? What causes the jump from 1.2... to 2.1?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. The [ ] is meant to be the checkbox. When I print out the document, I want to be able to make checkmarks after I complete that step in the procedure.  The 1.x to 2.1 jump would be the next section of the list.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to achieve using [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). Specifically, you can create a `checklist` that emulates `enumerate` (op to `3` levels, say), and define specific `label`s for each level.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\newcommand{\checkbox}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{.7\baselineskip}~}}

\newlist{checklist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[checklist,1]{label={\arabic*.~\checkbox},ref=\arabic*,leftmargin=3em}
\setlist[checklist,2]{label={\thechecklisti.\arabic*.~\checkbox},ref={\thechecklisti.\arabic*}}
\setlist[checklist,3]{label={\thechecklistii.\arabic*.~\checkbox},ref={\thechecklistii.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{checklist}
  \item First
  \item Second
    \begin{checklist}
      \item Sub-first
      \item Sub-second
      \item Sub-third
      \item Sub-last
    \end{checklist}
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{checklist}

\end{document}
```

Since the `label`s contain a `\checkbox` each, we define a `\checkbox`-less `ref` for each item so that isn't included when you use `\label`-`\ref`.

You can play around and redefine your own style of `\checkbox` as needed (like `\newcommand{\checkbox}{{[~~]}}`).